# How to display graphics in full screen in Protected mode

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86, operating-system

I am trying to write a simple system kernel. At present, I have successfully entered the Protected mode and paging mode, but I found that the bios interrupt no longer works (of course not), but I hope to display something on the screen.

I have searched for a lot of information online, but most of it is based on BIOS interrupts or can only display partial screens (800x600). I hope to find a way to manipulate the pixels of the entire screen.

Comment: If you boot in legacy 16-bit mode (instead of a modern UEFI application), see https://wiki.osdev.org/VESA_Video_Modes .  Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions mentions 32-bit mode.